# jQuery Event Listeners Handling This

Tags: jquery, this, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have demonstrated 4 different syntaxes to attached an event listener. Per https://api.jquery.com/click/ .click() attached to Button 2 is shorthand for .on( "click", handler ) attached to Button 3.  However, Button 3 does not recognize 'this', as it outputs 'undefined' in the log whereas all the other buttons return their button ID.  I instead created a different function for Button 4 to explicitly pass 'this' when using .click().

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Handle This</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function handleThis1(e) { console.log(`Event: ${e.type}, This: ${this.id}`); }
    function handleThis2(e, t) { console.log(`Event: ${e.type}, This: ${t.id}`); }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', handleThis1);
            $("#button2").on('click', handleThis1);
            $("#button3").click(function (event) { handleThis1(event) });
            $("#button4").click(function (event) { handleThis2(event, this) });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Button 1">
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Button 2">
    <input type="button" id="button3" value="Button 3">
    <input type="button" id="button4" value="Button 4">
</body>
</html>
```

So why does button 2 recognize 'this' but button 3 does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do

```
handleThis1(event);
```

the context of the function call is Window. hence `this` in `handleThis1` function is `window`

if you change the way to call this function to

```
    handleThis1.apply(this, [event]);
```

then the context is button3

Comment: After posting I did figure out this was calling the Window object by removing the .id property.  But this will work.  But now I have something new to learn about - this apply method.  That's new to me, but I'm very much a novice. Thanks.